# Computation of Intersection points of an algebraic curve and a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

`Sorry for long post...`

In Example 9.3 of the lecture notes of MA40188 Algebraic Curves (2016) by Ziyu Zhang from ShanghaiTech ([Lecture notes](https://ziyuzhang.github.io/ma40188/Lecture_Notes_Long.pdf)), he goes like `By the method of in the proof of Theorem 8.8`

### Example 9.3

[image]

### Theorem 8.8 and its proof

[image]

### My understanding of the computation method

I understood that `the computation method in the proof of Theorem 8.8` that he meant as the following way; given the found linear factorisation;
$f(x, y, -ax/c - by/c) = (r_1 x + s_1 y) \cdots (r_d x + s_d y) = 0$, each factor $(r_i x + s_i y)$ determines a solution $[x : y] = [-s_i : r_i]$ which gives the point $p_i = [- s_i : r_i : a s_i / c - b r_i / c] \in L \cap D$ where $L$ and $D$ follow from the proof (See L1 and L3 of the proof).

### My question

Now, back on the example 9.3, I tried to reproduce the part `the third intersection point R of AB and C to be R = [0 : 1 : 1]`.
Then, as in `the method in proof of Theorem 8.8`, he replaced $z$ w/h $-ax / c - by / c$ so I tried to solve $y^2z - x^3 + 4xz^2 - z ^3 = 0$ w.r.t $x$ to find the form of $x$ in terms of y and z. But I'm stuck at $- x ^3 + 4xz^ = z^3 - y^2 z$ and don't know how to go from here...

Could someone help me?

Comment: Note: I've started following his lecture notes as I was stuck at understanding Sec 2.8 of Reid's Undergraduate algebraic geometry book.

Comment: You just have to follow the instruction you already wrote down, replace $z$ with $-ax/c-by/c=y$. Then the next equation should contain no $z$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann hmm, I'm not seeing what you are seeing, i think. So I understood that the author obtained $ax/c−by/c=z$ by solving $ax + by + cz = 0$ w.r..t $z$. But our algebraic equation of interest isn't this one, right? So, how can we obtain that relationship?

Comment: This is the line equation that was previously determined, $-4y+4z=0$, giving $(a,b,c)=(0,-4,4)$. It is stated quite clearly that the line that is intersected with the variety is $L=V(ax+by+cz)$, and for the line of interest $AB$ such a form is calculated with the determinant.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh, now I see. So $D$ in the proof is supposed to be based on our new algebraic function $y^2z - x^3 + 4xz^2 - z ^3 = 0$ so that we are supposed to seek the intersection of $L$ before and the new $D$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they're doing here is using the linear form to eliminate a variable, so that we're left with a form in two variables, which can be factored.

In this case, the linear form is $4y - 4z$, which has the same zero set as $y - z$, so to solve this, we just plug in $z = y$ into the cubic form and factor.

Explicitly, our equation becomes $$y^3 - x^3 + 4xy^2 - y^3 = 4xy^2 - x^3.$$ But now, we can factor this as $x(4y^2 - x^2) = x(2y - x)(2y + x)$. This will then give us the intersection points $[0: 1 : 1], [2: 1: 1],$ and $[-2 : 1 : 1]$ as required.

Comment: Thank you so much again, Daniel! I overlooked to utilise the found linear factor $y - z = 0$!